# "Детский сад" - это слово или словосочетание?

Tags: общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка

Задумался, а название учреждения "детский сад" это что; слово, словосочетание или вообще фразеологизм?

В словосочетании мы можем без потери смысла произвести инверсию. Например, мы можем сказать клише "генерал армии", можем, нарушить клише, и сказать "армии генерал", при этом смысл словосочетания не изменится.

С "детским садом" такое не получится "сад детский" - это неизвестное явление с непонятным значением. В немецком, откуда заимствовано понятие детский сад это одно слово, *der Kindergarten*

Comment: А "капитан-лейтенант", "подполковник", "контр-адмирал", "генерал армии", "маршал авиации", "адмирал флота Советского Союза" это слова, словосочетания или вообще фразеологизмы?

Comment: Если  скажем  армии  генерал,  смысл  изменится.  Если  детский  сад  перевод  немецкого  термина,  то  перевести  его  можно  только  словосочетанием.  Хотя  слово  детсад  тоже  уже  есть.

Comment: Кроме  этого,  в  значении  "детский  сад"  употребляется  ещё  и  слово  "садик".

Comment: @bernard, в чём по вашему разница между "генерал армии" и "армии генерал" вне официального стиля речи?

Comment: Генерал армии -  это  звание.  А  армии  генерал - возможен  лишь  в  разговорах  неграмотных  старушек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Детский сад — это термин, обозначающий  образовательное учреждение для детей дошкольного возраста, а  термины - это устойчивые сочетания, применяемые в различных областях жизни. Название «детский сад» -  дословный перевод с немецкого  языка слова «kindergarten», так как первые детские сады появились в Германии. Таким образом, немецкое по происхождению название  из  19 века  в неизменном виде прошло через все войны и революции и вписалось в современную систему российского образования.

НЕМНОГО ИСТОРИИ

Сейчас кажется, что  "детский сад" называется так потому, что предназначен для  детей, которых мы должны выращивать, как цветы в саду, но это не совсем так.  Изобретателем  детского сада, считается Ф. Фрёбель (1782 -1852), немецкий педагог и теоретик дошкольного воспитания. В 40-х годах XIX века он открыл «первое учреждение по уходу за детьми» в небольшом городке Цорбих. По стечению обстоятельств оно разместилось в бывшей гостинице «У дворцового сада». Направляясь туда с детьми, горожане говорили: «Мы идём в сад». А какой сад? – Правильно, детский!

http://www.kalyakimalyaki.ru/paper363.html

В  России  детский сад появляется в Санкт-Петербурге в 60-е годы XIX века.  Детские сады «приживались» чрезвычайно медленно: возникали по инициативе частных лиц, были платными и предназначались для детей городских имущих сословий. С 1900 года о детсадах начало заботиться государство, выделяя на них средства. После революции 1917 года, детсады стали массовым явлением.

Comment: София, зачем вы в свои ответы ставите копипасты из сомнительных источников? 

Чтобы убедится в том, что история про дворцовый сад в Цорбихе чушь, не нужно знать философию Фрёбеля (у него как раз выращивать детей как цветы), не нужно знать, что города Цорбиха никогда не существовало, а первый детский сад был в Бланкенбурге.  Нужно лишь подумать, по какой же это причине горожане в **маленьком** городке, не знали какие у них в городе сады и чем занимаются в этом "учреждении", да как слово появившееся столь странным образом, могло распространиться по всему миру? Правильно - никак.

Comment: Марк Из, а зачем так много патетики - право же, предмет того не стоит, берегите эмоции для других случаев. Можно коротко и корректно внести свои поправки, если ответ Вам кажется неточным. Мне интереснее было бы услышать Ваш комментарий по поводу терминологического словосочетания. Кроме того, Вам отвечали и комментировали Ваш вопрос другие люди, Вы хотя бы из вежливости что-нибудь и кому-нибудь ответили по существу.

Comment: А по существу, у вас только первое предложение в виде тезиса без доказательств, всё остальное занимательные исторические и псевдоисторические сведения. Причем этот тезис не раскрыт и даже не объяснено, что под ним подразумевается более конкретно, в Википедии 10 подкатегорий устойчивых сочетаний. Вот и получается, что обсуждать приходится левые сведения.

Исправлять чужие ответы, на предмет предоставленных сведений тут непринято. Откуда я могу знать, что вы этим хотите сказать.

Comment: А Вы бы так и вопрос ставили. Вот нашел я в Википедии 10 подкатегорий устойчивых сочетаний. Не подскажите, для детского сада хотя бы один вариант подходит? Мы бы уж и постарались. Думаю, что все эти категории относятся к фразеологизмам разговорного стиля. Никто терминологические сочетания вида "электрическое поле, трудовой договор, общественная организация" на воспроизводимость не анализирует, а уж "словом" точно не назовет. И по поводу здешних традиций. Думаю, что здесь принято по возможности правильно отвечать на вопросы, совместно их редактируя. Кстати, "не принято" пишется раздельно.

Comment: >И по поводу здешних традиций. Думаю, что здесь принято по возможности правильно отвечать на вопросы, совместно их редактируя/

Если вы будете делать свои ответы общими, то совместно их редактировать вполне возможно, редактировать же авторские ответы на предмет изменения их смысла - неэтично, иначе неизбежно начнутся войны правок.

>Кстати, "не принято" пишется раздельно.

Спасибо, опечатка.

Минус, за популяризацию ложных сведений.

Comment: Большое спасибо, Марк Из, за минусовку. Обычно люди, вопросы которых здесь рассматривают, говорят отвечающим "спасибо" или в самом вопросе, или после ответа. Странные привычки, не правда ли?

Comment: >Странные привычки, не правда ли?

Согласен, мне тоже не нравится, когда благодарят за ответ в вопросе, а тем более в комментарии, так как это отвлекает без какой-либо пользы.

Answer (score 0):

Может, надо учитывать в каком дискурсе это слово,словосочетание или вообще фразеологизм употребляются?